# Ubuntu version to Install for Driver compatibility

Tags: drivers, nvidia, kernel, graphics

I 'm planning to install Ubuntu on a laptop with Intel i5-7300HQ and nvidia 1050Ti. The laptop has both dedicated graphics and HD630 integrated from the CPU.

I 'd like to isntall 16.04.2 on it but I 'm not sure if it's kernel version has the required drivers. From which kernel release and onwards kabylake support and pascal/hybrid gpu's can work (production like suuport not experimental preferably)? (I know that I ll also need nvidia proprietary drivers). Can I do it or do I have to go with 16.10?

P.S. Will 16.10 be enough or should I wait and go straight to 17.04 when it's out?

The reason I'm asking is that I 'm not keen to fully installing an OS from scratch ~4 times within 16 months if I can avoid it.

Comment: This is why the Ubuntu installer has a 'Try without installing' option - so you can test it on your hardware without commitment.

Comment: There are no drivers for this GPU in the kernel. You will need to install proprietary drivers. You don't need to wait for anything. You can install 16.04.2. And 16.04.2 is the same as 16.04 in terms of drivers.

Comment: I know about try without installing but I don't know how to test that my CPU is supported, that's why I 'm asking if people know which kernel version has full kaby lake support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The laptop arrived and I tried Ubuntu 16.04.2 from a live USB. Everything, that I knew how to test, seemed to be working (e.g. suspend). Even the hybrid graphics gave no problem (I was prepared to boot with nouveau.modeset = 0 but didn't need to).

I do plan to upgrade the kernel whenever it gets released for the LTS version.

TLDR: 16.04.2 supports kaby lake i5-7300hq and nvidia 1050Ti.